# What file format should I choose, for simple text/info/comments files?

Tags: file, format, comments

First post right there, and not actual problem, but still, a question :)
If it is a problem - it's more like first world problem :D Thanks for answer anyway!

tl;dr:
**What file format should I choose, for simple text/info/comments files?**

I start my adventure with some basic webdev technologies, I do code in VS Code and I like it,
I do lot of tutorials, and sometimes they (teachers) mention some shortcuts, or commands, or even whole scripts - which I want to write down for later, or I want to summarize my lesson, what Ive learned.

I do it in some new separate file, with no extension.
Still, I do use some comments to make sections in my file (I use Better Comments ext.) and I've started to think - is there some special file extension/format, that coders use, for separate files which are not executable, but have only infos? Maybe like manuals, readme etc.

I know, maybe it's silly, but still - want to know!
Thank you for answers! :)

I save file without extension, I open it in VS Code anyway.
I use  comment syntax, and some Better Comments colorization.

Comment: I found and used .md - markdown syntax. 
Really easy to use and implement, and also easy file preview inside VS Code.